# Form with graphics distorts

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

In C# i have created a function to draw a triangle between a `rich-textbox` and a `RectangleShape` object.

below is what i wrote.

```
Graphics Pointer = this.CreateGraphics();

Pointer.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
Pointer.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color.White), GetTriangle(this.FetchRectangle));
Pointer.Dispose();
```

The `gettriangle()` function returns an array of points(3 vertices of the triangle.) But when i try running the pgm, the form's background (which is set to black color) now takes a blurred and distorted background image of wat is shown in the computer screen.

How can i get the triangle image without distorting the form background?

Comment: `Form with graphics distorts` - then use a vector-based technology such as WPF, instead of a bitmap-based one such as winforms. Vector graphics, by definition, can be scaled to infinity without losing quality.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is cause due to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_blanking_interval
The solution is double buffering. and waiting Vertical retrace. I couldn't find example how to do htis but this is the way to go

see:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9f07dec1-1b04-419c-b604-44fd74027161/windows-forms-double-buffering-?forum=csharpgeneral